# Точка после кавычек с восклицательным знаком

Tags: пунктуация, кавычки

Мы проводим лекции в рамках ежегодной международной конференции «Земля — наш общий дом!».

Нужна ли точка в конце предложения?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Да, точка нужна.

[**О сочетаниях знаков препинания**](http://new.gramota.ru/biblio/readingroom/rules/165-oszp) (Грамота.ру)

> Примечание 1. Если перед закрывающими кавычками стоит знак вопросительный, или восклицательный, или многоточие, то те же самые знаки не повторяются после кавычек; неодинаковые же знаки, если они требуются в силу характера соответствующих частей текста, могут ставиться перед закрывающими кавычками и после них, например:
>
> Читали ли вы роман Чернышевского «Что делать?»
>
> Но:
>
> Драматический кружок готовит к постановке пьесу «В бой!».

[**Кавычки и другие знаки**](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=178) (Розенталь)

> *Я читаю роман А. И. Герцена «Кто виноват?».*